# Rails 3 routing - passing params from routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 2.3.5 you could do something like this inside the routes.rb file:

```
map.root :controller => "pages", :action => "show", :id => 3
```

In rails 3 I haven't found any way to pass a specific parameter (like in rails 2.3.5 with :id => 3).

I know I can handle it from the controller and have the same result (which I did), but I was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing in rails 3 from the routes.rb or has it changed because it is better practice for some reason?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Are you sure the following doesn't work?

```
root :to => "pages#show", :id => 3
```

Comment: Well, it works, I thought I had tested it but now I tried it to be sure and it is working... thank you! It was in front of my eyes :)