# Rails 3.1 empty parameters from routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, parameters

I have migrated a project from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3.1 and I have the following issue. Using any of these routes configs:

```
match 'help/*details' => 'help#index'

# or

match ':controller/:action/:id'
```

The matching works, but inside the specific action (from controller) I don't have the `details` parameter or the `id`. `raise params.inspect` returns `{}`.

This thing happens only with parameters from routes (if let's say I use JavaScript for an ajax request, parameters are sent and received as they should be).

Comment: I found the issue: it was an open id auth plugin messing up with my parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question here [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533960/rails-3-routing-passing-params-from-routes-rb)

try:

```
match 'help/*details' => 'help#index', detail=> "something?"
```

Comment: That's a different issue. I am using normal routing config (like match ':controller/:action/:id' ) And when I call /users/show/1 I get no error, but in users controller, in show action, params[:id] is nil and should be 1.